# How can I click on coordinates on globe?

Tags: three.js

I am using chrome experiment's globe http://globe.chromeexperiments.com and I would like to click on any color coordinates to show popup but event listener is not being called. can somebody assist me how to do it?

Comment: You need to implement picking. See http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try casting a ray from the camera into the scenery and then getting the intercepts. See the docs for [rayCaster](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster).

What you would do is create a new rayCaster object, then get the mouse coordinates of the user's screen. You would need to create some kind of "onclick" event on the parent element of the canvas. 
Once the event occurs, the rayCaster object has a property which handles our situation, "setFromCamera". However, you need to provide it a list of all of the objects that you are interested in intersecting, that is all of the rectangles.

So you code would look something like this, note that I used jQuery for this:

```
var rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

var onClickEventHandler = function(e) {
    //Save the mouse data as a vector
    //width and height pertain to the size of the canvas.
    var mousePosition = new THREE.Vector3((e.offsetX / width) * 2 - 1, 
        -(e.offsetY / height) * 2 + 1,
        0.5);
    rayCaster.setFromCamera(mousePosition, camera);
    //"objects" is the array of meshes that you care about the user intersecting
    var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObjects(objects);
}
```

What is contained inside the "intersects" array is all of the items from the "objects" array which ere intersected by the ray in the order of intersection. You are likely interested in the first element of this array.

I don't know if that globe utility provides a better way of doing it, what I showed is the generic way of selecting an object in the scenery.